# Deploy aplicação Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, linux, deploy

Estou com problemas para subir minha aplicação para ambiente de produção.
Tentei por diversas vezes como encontro nos passo a passo e documentação, mas o erro persiste.

**Cenário atual:**
Subi o projeto, com o nome de backend, para o diretório no mesmo nível do www:
[image: raiz]

Dentro do www estão os arquivos do front-end, que foram desenvolvidos por outra pessoa:
[image: www]

Nesse mesmo diretório criei a pasta admin, onde estão os arquivos da pasta Public do projeto:
[image: admin]

Rodei os scripts para instalação do composer e migrações, mas ao tentar acessar outra página que não a rota "/" (home), ele não encontra, como mostrado na imagem abaixo: 
[image: erro]

Sei que o ideal é que os arquivos do Public do meu projeto estejam no WWW, mas como lá já estão os arquivos do front, criei a pasta "admin", na intenção de que o administrador tenha acesso a um painel para administrar o conteúdo da página.

Alguém sabe dizer onde estou errando?
Grato desde já.

Comment: a hospedagem e compartilhada ou é uma VPS ?

Comment: É em um servidor próprio da empresa, disponibilizado para essa aplicação.

Comment: Qual sistema  operacional ? e tem git nele ?

Comment: Debian 9 
Com git

Comment: o projeto foi upado para algum git ?

Comment: Foi sim. Ta aqui: git@github.com:thiagomrvieira/pinheiro.git

Comment: Vou Responder com um passo a passo pra tu upar esse projeto

Answer (score 2):

Vamos fazer uma instalação do zero do seu projeto, (creio que é a melhor forma):

Acesse o seu projeto pelo terminal `ssh`, navegue até o diretório **www** (normalmente fica dentro de `/var/www/`)

Dentro do diretório clone o seu projeto com o seguinte comando:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/thiagomrvieira/pinheiro.git
```

Após a conclusão acesse o diretório do projeto (`pinheiro`)

`$ cd pinheiro`

Crie o arquivo `.env` (vi que não fez commit do [`.env.example`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example) *(clique no link para ver o modelo)*) 
Após a criação edite para adicionar as configurações de banco de dados e etc.

> Ou você pode definir essas informações do `.env` também dentro do diretório `config/database.php` ou `config/app.php` e etc..

Instale os pacotes com o seguinte comando do [**composer**](https://getcomposer.org/):

`composer install`

Aguarde ele concluir vamos criar a chave do projeto para isso rode o seguinte comando abaixo, para gerar a nova chave:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Pronto agora temos o projeto configurado e pronto pra iniciar a importação dos das tabelas com o `migrate`:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Aguarde a conclusão do comando caso não ocorra algum erro o banco de dados já foi importado.

Você pode testar com o comando:

```
php artisan serve --host 127.0.0.1
```

> O **`--host 127.0.0.1`** é um parâmetro opcional para você determinar o ip do servidor *(necessário em conexões externas)*.

Pronto, com a aplicação funcional, agora vamos a parte do **Linux**, e para isso vamos trabalhar com **virtual hosts**. creio que seja a melhor forma de se fazer isso.

Acesse o diretório  `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` crie o um arquivo com o nome do seu domínio terminado por `.conf` por exmeplo: `abcd.com.br.conf`, eu por costume já tenho um modelo aqui pronto e vou usa-lo como exemplo.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@pinheiro.com.br
    DocumentRoot /var/www/AdmMedico/public
    ServerName  pinheiro.com.br
    ServerAlias www.pinheiro.com.br

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
<Directory "/var/www/pinheiro/public">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Já meio que pré configurei para seu caso, presumindo que você  use o domínio **pinheiro.com.br**, caso não seja troque para o seu uso.

Criando o basta reiniciar o serviço do apache e que está pronto,

```
service apache2  restart
```

Agora basta acessar por `pinheiro.com.br` que irá carrega a pagina como deveria.

> Para mais informações sobre [**Virtual Host**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-configurar-apache-virtual-hosts-no-ubuntu-16-04-pt)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, @Bulfaitelo. Na verdade o que eu queria era manter um projeto já existente no diretório e subir o meu em um subdiretório como pinheiro.com.br/admin. Acabei criando um outro diretório com outro domínio e e a aplicação do front consumindo a API com os dados do backend. DE qualquer forma, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez não tenha explicado muito bem.
O que eu queria fazer era manter um projeto já existente no meu diretório e criar um subdiretorio como pinheiro.com.br/admin com o meu projeto Laravel.

Não consegui configurar para que funcionasse assim. Como o servidor é próprio, acabei criando outro domínio e subindo o projeto em outro diretório, onde desenvolvi uma API que foi consumida pelo projeto inicial (o que já estava la).