# Definir diretório para subdomínio via HTACCESS

Tags: php, htaccess

Criei um sub-domínio e gostaria que o diretório dele fosse uma pasta específica.

Por exemplo:

**Sub-domínio:** teste.site.com.br

**Pasta:** site/pasta/

Eis o que tentei:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^teste.site.com.br$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ pasta/ [L]
```

Comment: Você pode definir isso no próprio apache, mas vou responder com um possível que adequei a seu caso, veja e funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue a possível solução.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^teste.site.com.br$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pasta/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Testa ai é me fala, se funciona para o seu caso.

Mas pra adiantar já vou deixar o `sites-enabled` do apache pra você aqui:

"Acesse o diretório `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` crie o um arquivo com o nome do seu domínio terminado por `.conf` por exmeplo: `abcd.com.br.conf`, eu por costume já tenho um modelo aqui pronto e vou usa-lo como exemplo."

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@pinheiro.com.br
    DocumentRoot /var/www/AdmMedico/public
    ServerName  pinheiro.com.br
    ServerAlias www.pinheiro.com.br

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
<Directory "/var/www/pinheiro/public">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**Referencia** :[Deploy aplicação Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/362035/deploy-aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-laravel/362063#362063)

Comment: Eu testei o teu código do htaccess, mas apareceu um erro: https://i.imgur.com/vBjvczC.png

Acredito que seja por falta de permissão da pasta, entrei em contato com a hospedagem para verificar...

Comment: Isso é erro de ssl, seu site tem https ? pode ser que o certificado seja só para o domínio principal. tenta acessar como http:// (eu não se se você realmente tem https. caso sim veja com a hospedagem o certificado)

Comment: Sim, cada vez que é criado um diretório é um parto. É uma empresa de cyber security aí eles bloqueiam praticamente tudo aí cada vez tem que entrar em contato com eles para eles ir dando permissões aos poucos até que dê certo. Mas acredito que está correto este código, pq coloquei o subdomínio/ um diretório que não existe e deu erro diferente. Assim que me liberarem eu confirmo a resposta, acredito estar correta...

Comment: @Lucas Blz, eles certamente trabalham com regras restritivas, se não funcionar comentar o erro aqui que vamos alinhando até ficar certo.

Comment: você que manja mais: o problema realmente é no https, tirei o direcionamento do htaccess e o site ao menos mostrou, porém erro 404 (ou seja, não está buscando o diretório correto), mas a minha dúvida, pode ser sem sentido: eu direciono tudo para https, mas gostaria de direcionar somente esse sub-domínio para http, tem como fazer isto?

Comment: Da uma olhada nisso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/364158/redirecinamento-301-htaccess-com-e-sem-www-para-https/364160#364160 ele e pega parte do https. no caso remove o redirecionamento o diretório, e testa, se funciona realmente o problema está no caminho, atente para caso for colocar o diretório completo.